# how to write a script that opens cmd and runs a command?

Tags: command-line, script, batch

I would like to write a script that opens the cmd and runs some command that I wrote.
How can I do it?
and when I save the file - the ending is .txt? 
i'm not familiar with it so any help would be appreciated!

thanks!

Comment: you just write the script in a text file and save as `.bat`. There are tons of resources out there and since you already about batch files, I'm sure you could find them. Try it out for yourself, and then come back if you run into issues. You could even click your own batch tag and look through some of the questions for examples.

Answer (score 3):

Notepad by default saves with a ".txt" filetype. When you are looking at the file you saved in Windows Explorer, rename the file (press F2) and change the `.txt` to `.bat`.